# Combine two array values to make them key=>value format

Tags: php, arrays

I am having two arrays like this

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => username 
  [1] => avatar 
) 
Array 
( 
  [0] => name 
  [1] => 4.jpg 
)
```

Here, I need to get these values in the following format

`'username'=>name,'avatar'=>4.jpg`

i.e., merge the same key values in the above format..

How should I do this,..Someone help me..

If you think that my title is wrong,Please change it into correct format.

Thanks,

Comment: use `$final = array_combine($fist_array,$second_array)`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand..You mean the light as power !!!... :)

Comment: ha ha ha yes  power :):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$c = array_combine($a, $b);`

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_combine()`

```
$final_array = array_combine($fist_array,$second_array);
```

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php